# Is there a way to display history of onSnapshot connections in javascript Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to display history of "onSnapshot" calls? I know that my application is calling it multiple times, and I would like to debug it from the PoV of Firestore.

Also, is it possible to display active subscriptions?

Thanks!